# Undefined property: Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\BeanstalkdJob:: $name

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, task-queue, beanstalkd

I'm using **beanstalkd** with **Laravel** to queue some tasks but I'm having trouble to send data to the function that handles the queue , Here is my code

```
//Where I call the function 

$object_st = new stdClass(); 
$object_st->Person_id = 2 ;

//If I do this: echo($object_st->Person_id); , I get 2 

Queue::push('My_Queue_Class@My_Queue_Function', $object_st );
```

And the function that handle the queue is the following

```
 public function My_Queue_Function( $Data )
{
    $Person_id = $Data->Person_id; //This generate the error 

    //Other code
}
```

The error  says:

> [ErrorException]
>   Undefined property: Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\BeanstalkdJob::$Person_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way queues work in 4.2 is different than 5; the first argument in the function that handles the queue task is actually a queue job instance, the second argument would be your data:

```
class SendEmail {

    public function fire($job, $data)
    {
        //
    }

}
```

As per example from the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queues#basic-usage).

Your code would therefor need to allow the first argument:

```
public function My_Queue_Function( $job, $Data )
{
    $Person_id = $Data['Person_id'];

    //Other code
}
```

Comment: Should I keep call it this way  `Queue::push('My_Queue_Class@My_Queue_Function', $object_st );`  @Luceos

Comment: Thanks , It works when I use `$Person_id = $Data['Person_id'];` not `$Person_id = $Data->Person_id;` You should consider to update your answer so it would help others in future